# Ошибка в SOAP-запросе

Tags: xml, gwt, клиент-сервер, soap

Отправляю SOAP запрос на сервер используя на клиентской части GWT, на серверной свой с++ сервер. Код в gwt выглядит так

```
RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, "http://myServerName/backEndDispatcher");
    builder.sendRequest(soapEnvelope, new RequestCallback(){
        public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
            int respStat = response.getStatusCode();
            if (respStat != 200) {
                return;
            }
            // ...               
        }
        public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
            // ...
        }
    });
}
```

Код SOAP-запроса

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope
   xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope"
   soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding">
  <soap:Body xmlns:c="http://myServerName/Product/C"
     xmlns:a="http://myServerName/Product/A"
     xmlns:b="http://myServerName/Product/B">
    <c:Event>
      <a:OnEvent>
        <b:Id>1</b:Id>
      </a:OnEvent>
    </c:Event>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

На сервер запрос приходит, но после двойного перевода строки ничего нет (самого пакета). В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: А как Вы определили, что больше ничего нет? С помощью wireshark надеюсь?

Comment: Все намного проще, у нас самописный сервер. Я посмотрел, что в сокет приходит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще, отправка данных в content-части GET-запроса - очень странная идея и не специфицирована RFC2616. Возможно поэтому, данные и не содержатся после двух переводов строк. Так ли необходимо использовать именно GET? Почем не использовать POST?